# On normal and algebraic numbers

Tags: number-theory

I have two questions regarding the nature of normal numbers.

**1.** It's been shown that 'almost all' real numbers are absolutely normal (meaning they're normal for any integer base $b>1$).

Since the set of irrational algebraic numbers is countable, it seems plausible that all members of that set are absolutely normal; Generally, numbers are believed to be normal unless we have a special reason to believe they're not.

By the look of it, though, we're still far from proving it- In fact, there hasn't been *any* algebraic number which was formally proven to be normal! So for all we know, *all* irrational algebraic numbers may not be absolutely normal. In fact, maybe none of them is normal to *any* base.

Is this possible? Or did I miss any result regarding the normality of algebraic numbers?

**2.** Has there ever been shown an example of a number which is normal in some base $b$, but is not absolutely normal? (For an example, someone may prove that $\pi$ is normal in base $2$, but not in base $10$)

If not, then how do we know that such numbers even exist? Maybe there's no difference between the terms "normal" and "absolutely normal", and every number that's normal in some base is normal in all bases?

---

Now, saying that normal numbers are hard to research is an understatement. It seems like even though the notions of probability and decimal notation have been there forever, we still hardly know anything about it.

What are the current tools that mathematicians use to investigate the subject? Has there been any interesting progress on it lately? (There's [this article](http://www.glyc.dc.uba.ar/santiago/papers/absnor.pdf) with explicit example of a computable, absolutely normal number, but that's about it)

Comment: For your second question, yes : see [this](http://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/alpha-6.pdf) article.

Comment: For your first question, in _On the Random Character of Fundamental Constant Expansions_ (by David H. Bailey and Richard E. Crandall), it can be read : "one could further conjecture that every irrational algebraic number is absolutely normal". See also _Algebraic irrational binary numbers cannot be fixed points of non-trivial constant-length or primitive morphisms_ (by J.-P. Allouche and L. Q. Zamboni) : "This conjecture is open and seems really out of reach".

Comment: You can have a look to Yann Bugeaud's [book](https://books.google.ch/books?id=NeEpoAf7k0IC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Bugeaud+yann&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjY54iy1ITMAhWkJZoKHW_4AHgQ6AEIMDAC) which has many references and proves some results about normal numbers and [rich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_sequence#Rich_numbers) numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the links! 

So we still don't have any example for an algebraic normal number, right?

Comment: You are right, we have no example of algebraic normal number yet… We don't even know any algebraic _rich_ number, I think. [This](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23547) question can probably be changed into "does $\sqrt 2$ contain 1000 consecutive zeroes (in base $10$)?", and the answer will be the same: I believe that this is expected, but unknown.